# need help creating a non-root systemd service

Tags: systemd

I'm using ubuntu 22 and currently have a user and group named "steam"

When I want to run my cs2 server , I first switch to steam user :

```
su steam
```

Then I run the following command :

```
cs2-server @public1 start
```

The above command doesn't run as root user and throws an error saying it's a security risk to run it as root so I have to create a systemd service that can be accessed by steam user .

The path to cs2-server is /usr/local/bin/cs2-server .

When I run the start command from steam user , I don't get prompt for a password as well which I think the service I create must not ask for a password either .

This is how I created a systemd service but had no luck :

```
[Unit]
Description=public 1 run
After=network.target

[Service]
User=steam
Group=steam
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cs2-server @public1 start
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How should I achieve what I want?

Comment: What do you mean "i don't get prompt for a password"?  SystemD services executed by the system can run as **any user** and therefore don't need user passwords to execute.  What password are you expecting to be asked about?

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"had no luck"*? What exactly happens when you try to enable/start the service? What do `systemctl status name-of-your-service` and/or `journalctl -xe -u name-of-your-service` report?

Comment: @ThomasWard I meant that when running command cs2-server public1 start as steam user , I don't get prompted for a password but when I created that systemd file that I sent above , when using systemctl start public1.service , it prompt me for a password .

Comment: @steeldriver when I run systemctl start public1.service , the service is not started . It doesn't run the cs2 instance . I will check the status and journalctl reports tonight when I get back home and I will edit the original post and include them . what I don't get is , currently /usr/bin/local/cs2-server is owned by root but I can run it without sudo and any password while I'm logged into steam user . now when creating systemd file , I think steam user can't access the systemd service I'm creating .

Comment: OK thanks I will check back later. FYI executables in `/usr/local/bin/` *should* be owned by root (but executable by others). You're getting a password prompt when starting the service because it's a systemd *system* service - that's also normal and nothing to do with who has permission to run the program itself.

Comment: @steeldriver I managed to get it to work by adding Type=forking to the systemd service file . I don't know how exactly it helped but it solved my case .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get that to work by adding :

Type=forking

So in general , here is how the service file looks :

```
[Unit]
Description=public 1 run
After=network.target

[Service]
User=steam
Group=steam
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cs2-server @public1 start
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```